# Editing UI Control Map, changing control references

Tags: c#, wpf, window, coded-ui-tests

My problem is this, my main window's title is dynamic (it contains the version of the application), so when I recorded my coded ui tests, several objects were created for that window under the UIMap node in the UI Control Map named "MainWindow", "MainWindow1", "MainWindow2" etc... The only difference between them is the title.

So I changed the search property of the first "MainWindow" to "Contains" and just the name of the application in order to make it ignore the version part. But now my question is, how do I remove all the other main window objects and reference all of the UI actions and other controls (which are under the redundant window objects in the tree) to the "MainWindow" object?

I can't find any clean way to do this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Install Feature Pack 2 for Visual Studio, this will give you a graphical editor for the UIMap.
I also recommend using this extension: http://uimaptoolbox.codeplex.com/

Comment: Feature pack 2 applies to Visual Studio 2010. The UI Map editor comes as standard with Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the UIMap as xml (Right click the UIMap -> Open with -> xml (Text) Editor)

There, under `<UIMap>` find the `<Decendents>` tag of `MainWindow1` and `MainWindow2`.

copy all the `<UIObject ..>` nodes and move them to `MainWindow` under `<Descendants>`.

Then delete `MainWindow1` and `MainWindow2`  `<TopLevelWindow>` nodes.

Hope this helps